# Can't choose a Taxonomy term as a Context condition

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to create a context based on taxonomy. When I use the Context UI, the Taxonomy form is not populated with my taxonomy terms. [Here's a screenshot of my empty taxonomy selector.](http://75thtrombone.com/links/taxonomycontextfml.png)

I have three terms in one vocabulary, and all terms have at least one node associated with them.

What's going on?

Comment: There any reason why you can't just use a url path as your condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was user error. I wasn't the one to set up the taxonomy vocabulary in the first place, and it turns out that the guy who did set the vocabulary to be Tags. You can't use Tag vocabs in Context conditions. I unchecked the "Tags" box and now everything works as expected.